can't access json proprety
I'm trying to access the 'city' proprety of  this json but somehow it doesn't work , this is the json struct  :
"{\"ForSaleShopperPlatformFullRenderQuery{\\\"zpid\\\":28657235,\\\"platform\\\":\\\"DESKTOP_WEB\\\",\\\"formType\\\":\\\"OPAQUE\\\",\\\"contactFormRenderParameter\\\":{\\\"zpid\\\":28657235,\\\"platform\\\":\\\"desktop\\\",\\\"isDoubleScroll\\\":true},\\\"skipCFRD\\\":false,\\\"ompPlatform\\\":\\\"web\\\"}\":{\"property\":{\"listingDataSource\":\"Phoenix\",\"zpid\":28657235,\"city\":\"Boerne\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"homeStatus\":\"FOR_SALE\",\"address\":{\"streetAddress\":\"111 stone creek\",\"city\":\"Boerne\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"zipcode\":\"78006\",\"neighborhood\":null,\"community\":null,\"subdivision\":null},\"isListingClaimedByCurrentSignedInUser\":false,\"isCurrentSignedInAgentResponsible\":false,\"bedrooms\":3,\"bathrooms\":2,\"price\":345000,\"yearBuilt\":1999,\"streetAddress\":\"111 stone creek\",\"zipcode\":\"78006\",\"isCurrentSignedInUserVerifiedOwner\":false,\"propertyUpdatePageLink\":null,\"moveHomeMapLocationLink\":null,\"propertyEventLogLink\":null,\"editPropertyHistorylink\":null,\"collections\":{\"modules\":[{\"name\":\"Similar homes\",\"placement\":\"NEIGHBORHOOD\",\"propertyDetails\":[{\"miniCardPhotos\":[{\"url\":\"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/219307696092bb2d5e31698cba1c1e1f-p_c.jpg\"}],\"price\":315000,\"currency\":\"USD\",\"bedrooms\":3,\"bathrooms\":3,\"livingArea\":1729,\"livingAreaValue\":1729,\"livingAreaUnits\":\"Square Feet\",\"livingAreaUnitsShort\":\"sqft\",\"listingMetadata\":{\"comminglingCategoryIsRulesApplicable\":true},\"lotSize\":2874,\"lotAreaValue\":2874.96,\"lotAreaUnits\":\"Square Feet\",\"address\":{\"streetAddress\":\"130 Hampton Bend\",\"city\":\"Boerne\",

{
    "ForSaleShopperPlatformFullRenderQuery{\"zpid\":28657235,\"platform\":\"DESKTOP_WEB\",\"formType\":\"OPAQUE\",\"contactFormRenderParameter\":{\"zpid\":28657235,\"platform\":\"desktop\",\"isDoubleScroll\":true},\"skipCFRD\":false,\"ompPlatform\":\"web\"}": {
        "property": {
            "listingDataSource": "Phoenix",
            "zpid": 28657235,
            "city": "Boerne",
            "state": "TX",
            "homeStatus": "FOR_SALE",
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "111 stone creek",
                "city": "Boerne",
                "state": "TX",
                "zipcode": "78006",
                "neighborhood": null,
                "community": null,
                "subdivision": null
            },

this is the code :
key = 'ForSaleShopperPlatformFullRenderQuery{"zpid":28657235,"platform":"DESKTOP_WEB","formType":"OPAQUE","contactFormRenderParameter":{"zpid":28657235,"platform":"desktop","isDoubleScroll":true},"skipCFRD":false,"ompPlatform":"web"}'
        city = data["props"]["pageProps"]["componentProps"]["gdpClientCache"][key]['property']['city']

i get error :
print(data["props"]["pageProps"]["componentProps"]["gdpClientCache"]['ForSaleShopperPlatformFullRenderQuery{\\"zpid\":28657235,\\"platform\\":\\"DESKTOP_WEB\\",\\"formType\\":\\"OPAQUE\\",\\"contactFormRenderParameter\\":{\\"zpid\\":28657235,\\"platform\\":\\"desktop\\",\\"isDoubleScroll\\":true},\\"skipCFRD\\":false,\\"ompPlatform\\":\\"web\\"}'])
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

tried also
key = "ForSaleShopperPlatformFullRenderQuery{\"zpid\":28657235,\"platform\":\"DESKTOP_WEB\",\"formType\":\"OPAQUE\",\"contactFormRenderParameter\":{\"zpid\":28657235,\"platform\":\"desktop\",\"isDoubleScroll\":true},\"skipCFRD\":false,\"ompPlatform\":\"web\"}"

still doesn't work

Make a [mcve] and provide the full error traceback and valid JSON.  That snip of JSON doesn't show the full path you are accessing.

Your two key versions are equivalent, and the error indicates you are indexing a string.  Since there are extra keys you haven't shown, [edit] the question to have an exact sample and code that can be copied and run to reproduce the issue.

Thank you for  your comment,   just  for clarification, the error has to do with that key  , i can't get  any data after the  ForSale...  key, I just wanna  access anything after that key, and  the json data is   large  I can't  post it here

You don’t have to post all the data, do some debugging and cut out all the data except the keys you are accessing to reproduce the failure and post that small example. You’d very likely figure it out if you just follow those steps.

First of all, your json example is not complete as I can't see these keys.

["props"]["pageProps"]["componentProps"]["gdpClientCache"]

So I tried data[key]['property']['city'], and it works.

I think the problem is at this key gdpClientCache. It must have returned a string value but not the json example you showed us. That's why the program wants you to use an integer as the index.
Double check the return value of each key and you should be able to solve the problem.

yes, it returned a string, but i still don't know what to do to  get that  city    in this situation

Never  mind, I   understood what should  be done   and solved it  , thank   you so     much for your  help

You have to make sure data["props"]["pageProps"]["componentProps"]["gdpClientCache"] is returning the correct json(dict) value.

No problem. :-)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
